# Connecting to Frontend DAapp with python using walletconnect (python, pyWalletConnect)

Tags: python

i am trying to create a bot in python to connect to a dapp. I'm trying to use pyWalletConnect lib, but it's new and challenging.

I have successfully retrieved the URI i need to connect to, but i have no clue on how to automate the connection, and how to sign the message asked from the dapp using pyWalletConnect.

Im open to use also a different lib if anyone knows.

thanks